# How to do a meta-analysis to synthesise studies across more than 2 variables?

Tags: meta-analysis, causality

Are there meta-analysis texts that deal with how to synthesise studies across more than 2 variables, and which also includes synthesising primary studies that deal with more than 2 variables at the same time? I read Cooper's book Research Syntheses and Meta-Analyses, and it was a very insightful read, but it only deals with 2 variables, and I would think that for a review to be really insightful for a discipline/science it needs to take stock of all the variables the researchers involved have studies, hence this question. And is meta-analysis across more than 2 variables the same as causal discovery as in https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v14/hyttinen13a.html?

It will be good to provide some readings.

Comment: The search term you need is probably multivariate meta-analysis or multi-level meta-analysis. There are a number of examples http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses and even if you do not use that software there are plenty of references to examples.